# resize canvas accordingly to screen size and printing images to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am developing a web application that uses the metaphore of a bookshelf.

Image horizontal:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2cmkiz8&s=8#.U8b0G3UphUY

Image vertical:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15g2m1e&s=8#.U8b0mnUphUY

I achieve this by setting a canvas all over the screen and then setting the books over the shelfs, redimension algorithm is working pretty nice resizing and repositioning books according to the shelf width and height.

Here is the .jsp page for the bookshelf:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Autobiographical Aid</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link
    href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300,300italic'
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/canvas.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

It is pretty simple it only has a canvas and everything is then set in the canvas.js.

```
(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var sources = {
        album : 'images/photo_album.jpg'
    };

    var clickedLink = false;

    //the image xpto is in the position
    //  (x,y)        (x+width,y)
    //  (x,y+height) (x+width,y+height)
    var imageLocations = {
        album : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, "photoalbum.jsp" ]
    };

    var linkToFollow = "";

    // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    function resizeCanvas() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var background = new Image();
        background.src = "images/bookshelf.png";

        background.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        };

        /**
         * Your drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will be reset when 
         * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
         */
        drawStuff(
                sources,
                function(images) {

                    var imgCrop = 0;// proporção de reduçao da imagem
                    var paddingSide = canvas.width * 0.04;
                    var imgX = canvas.width * 0.04; //posiçao de x 
                    var imgY = canvas.height * 0.07; // posiçao de y
                    var rackHeight = canvas.height * 0.34;
                    var maxBookDim = rackHeight;
                    var paddingBetweenBooks = canvas.width * 0.02;
                    var numImages = 0;
                    var rackWidth = 2 * 0.04; //padding plus 1 image
                    var first = true;
                    var done = false;
                    var imginLine = 0;
                    var rackSpacing = canvas.height * 0.05;

                    for ( var img in images) {
                        numImages++;
                        if (first) {
                            first = false;
                            rackWidth = rackWidth + maxBookDim;
                        } else {
                            rackWidth = rackWidth + paddingBetweenBooks
                                    + maxBookDim;
                            if (!done && rackWidth > canvas.width) {
                                imginLine = numImages - 1;
                                done = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(!done){
                        imginLine = numImages;
                    }

                    var rowCapacity = imginLine;
                    var imgX1 = 0;

                    var sizeForImage = (canvas.width - paddingSide * 2 - paddingBetweenBooks
                            * (imginLine - 1))
                            / imginLine;

                    for ( var img in images) {

                        //horizontal
                        if (images[img].width > images[img].height) {

                            imgCrop = images[img].width / rackHeight;
                            imgX1 = (sizeForImage - images[img].width / imgCrop) / 2;

                        } else {//vertical

                            imgCrop = images[img].height / rackHeight;
                            imgX1 = (sizeForImage - images[img].width / imgCrop) / 2;

                        }

                        var x = imgX + imgX1;
                        var y = imgY + rackHeight - images[img].height
                                / imgCrop;
                        var width = images[img].width / imgCrop;
                        var height = images[img].height / imgCrop;

                        context.drawImage(images[img], x, y, width, height);

                        imageLocations[img][0] = x;
                        imageLocations[img][1] = y;
                        imageLocations[img][2] = width;
                        imageLocations[img][3] = height;

                        if(canvas.width < canvas.height){
                            context.font = '50px Arial';
                        }else{
                            context.font = '30px Arial';
                        }

                        context.font = '30px Arial';                        
                        context.fillStyle = 'white';
                        context.fillText('Photo Album', x+25, y+(height/2)+10);

                        imgX = imgX + sizeForImage + paddingBetweenBooks;
                        rowCapacity -= 1;

                        if (rowCapacity == 0) {
                            imgY = imgY + rackSpacing + maxBookDim;
                            rowCapacity = imginLine;
                            imgX = paddingSide;
                        }

                    }

                    //add mouse listeners
                    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", on_mousemove, false);
                    canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);
                });
    }

    resizeCanvas();

    function drawStuff(sources, callback) {
        // do your drawing stuff here
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        // get num of sources
        for ( var src in sources) {
            numImages++;
        }
        for ( var src in sources) {
            images[src] = new Image();
            images[src].onload = function() {
                if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                    callback(images);
                }
            };
            images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
    }

    function on_mousemove(ev) {
        var x, y;

        // Get the mouse position relative to the canvas element.
        if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { //for firefox
            x = ev.layerX;
            y = ev.layerY;
        }

        x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
        y -= canvas.offsetTop;

        for ( var img in imageLocations) {

            //is the mouse over the image?
            if (x >= imageLocations[img][0]
                    && x <= (imageLocations[img][0] + imageLocations[img][2])
                    && y >= imageLocations[img][1]
                    && y <= (imageLocations[img][1] + imageLocations[img][3])) {
                document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
                clickedLink = true;
                linkToFollow = imageLocations[img][4];
                break;
            } else {
                document.body.style.cursor = "";
                clickedLink = false;
                linkToFollow = "";
            }

        }
    }

    //if the link has been clicked, go to link
    function on_click(e) {
        if (clickedLink) {
            window.location = "photoalbum.jsp";
            //document.getElementById('book').style.display = 'none';
            //document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
})();
```

in canvas.js i check for screen dimensions, repositioning the books and image resizing accordingly to new dimensions.

although i am getting the desired behaviour, several times when i **first** load the page the book you can see in the pictures does not appear, forcing me to reload the page several times until it does or resizing the browser window.

The code works, but why do i get this bug when i first load it?

The problem seems to be in the listener i am adding to the code:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", on_mousemove, false);
canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);
```

they are added so i know when the user clicks inside a book and use it as a hiperlink to another location.

If i dont put them it loads perfectly the first time but then the user cant proceed to the book.

Answer (score 0):

Script checks screen size on page load, so when you resize window, page does not load, and script think that screen size didn't change.

Why don't you try to accomplish the task with media queries?

Comment: when i resize the page it works seamlessly, the problem is when it loads the first time it doesn't show the book. if i then resize it it works  from that point on very well